# Converting data frame into list

Tags: dataframe, jupyter-notebook

[image]I have following code

```
subset = example.iloc[0:100,0]
print(subset)

0     0.467976
1    -0.358893
2    -0.501840
3     0.204886
4     0.354628
        ...   
95    1.106521
96   -0.540543
97   -0.101980
98    0.632107
99    1.009779
Name: one, Length: 100, dtype: float64
```

**I Wanna convert it into something look like [0.467976300189, -0.358893469543, -0.50184039929, 0.20488621220199998, ...].**

If I use

```
subset.values.tolist()
```

It shows something like

```
[[0.467976300189],
 [-0.358893469543],
 [-0.50184039929],
 [0.204886212202],
 [0.354627914484],
 [1.81748001608],
 [-0.776764319165],
 [-0.913134961617],
 [0.358479538224],
 [-1.74087710829],
 [0.24056373835],
 [0.764018252198],
 [0.571034923177],
 [2.31765810894],
 [1.54777073472],
 [-1.31060811665],
 [-0.0884964396951],
 [-0.0186628260149],
 [-0.0701272145463],
 [-0.194677940725],
 [-0.248617847177],
 [-1.09154895394],
 [0.641404300148],
 [1.21640846838]
```

which is a little bit different from what I want.

Any idea?

If I use ```python
subset_list = subset.column.to_list()

````
```python
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-effce8140c99> in <module>
----> 1 subset_list = subset.column.to_list()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5463             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5464                 return self[name]
-> 5465             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5466 
   5467     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'
````

Comment: Use `df.column.to_list()`

Comment: it doesn't work @Luke :( It says 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'

Comment: Then please consider sharing a minimal reproducible example :)

Comment: what does this mean lol. Thanks for ur reply btw @Luke

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I meant, it would be great if you could share an example of your dataframe and the expected output you are trying to achieve

Comment: I edited questions a little bit lol. Sorry for inconvenience, I am Python beginner. I also highlight the result that I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following to have `subset` as the `list`

```
subset = example.iloc[0:100,0].to_list()
```